# Xcode error while compiling the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

My Xcode project was running all good, I connected my iPhone to transfer the build and since then I am getting these errors

> Unknown type name CGContextRef in file CGBitmapContext.h

I have been unable to solve this for sometime now.

Comment: In my experience, when you encounter an error like this, first try updating both xcode and OS to latest versions.

Comment: I have the latest Xcode

Answer (score 2):

Core Graphics, where the CG* stuff is defined, is imported by UIKit, so add this line:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

in the offending file

Comment: If you want this all over the app you can also use a prefix header (pch file) and add the import there

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean derived data in Xcode.
Xcode- Preferences - Locations - Derived Data - You must delete derived data from there. And clean project.

Comment: I did it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Faced the issue in Xcode 11.3.
Done everything related to derived data clear, pod remove and everything available on internet but no luck and the app was not debugging on real device.
Then thought that it could be the issue of Xcode crash, just removed the Xcode to trash and cleared the trash and then reinstalled the fresh copy of Xcode 11.3.
It worked for me, thanks to my assumption.